# Switch tab [active sheet] by script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a method to switch the tab (active sheet) from one to another by script?

As far as I can see, Activate() function on range or on sheet does not work this way.

Comment: ...`setActiveSheet`?

Comment: How do you tried to use the cited method?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in say Sheet1 and want to move to Sheet2:

```
function myFunction() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").activate();
}
```

The first time you try and run the above you have to grant authorisation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this didn't work for me. It didn't switch the tab.